# Math text scaling in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

I was wondering if anyone knew of a package or command I could use to prevent TeX from scaling  values in an equation. An example of this would be if you have a fraction in a fraction, the text ends up getting fairly small and hard to read. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Example:

```
\frac{5}{\frac{1}{2}}
```

the 1/2 in the denominator will be pretty small and  hard to read.

Comment: Without scaling it wouldn't fit into a line, right? Why not use the math environment or $$\frac{5}{\frac{1}{2}}$$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\dfrac` or `\tfrac` to force the size you want.

LaTeX questions will get better answers on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\cfrac` command for the _c_ontinued fraction.